# makefile, size of an executable, static/dynamic

Tags: dynamic, static, makefile, size

I have a makefile, for a C project with 2 sub-C-files and I can create two exe, one static and one dynamic.

But the static is lighter in space than the dynamic!
The programs can be launched and seems to be the sames

Is it normal?

Thank you very much, I have an exam in 2 days and I hope I will fix that problem :)

Simon

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall 
CFLAGS2 = -shared 
CFLAGS3 = -fPIC 
LIB_U_CAM_TTL = -l_projet_vision_u_cam_ttl 
LIB_SERIAL_LINUX = -l_projet_vision_serial_linux 
CHEMIN = -L/usr/local/lib 



lib_projet_vision_serial_linux.so: serial_linux.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS2) $^ -o $@
lib_projet_vision_u_cam_ttl.so: u_cam_ttl.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS2) $^ -o $@

lib_projet_vision_serial_linux.a : serial_linux.o
    ar -rv $@ $^ 
lib_projet_vision_u_cam_ttl.a : u_cam_ttl.o
    ar -rv $@ $^


projet_vision_dynamic: main_vision.c install
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS3) $^ $(CHEMIN) $(LIB_SERIAL_LINUX) $(LIB_U_CAM_TTL) -o $@

projet_vision_static: main_vision.c install
    $(CC) $^ $(CHEMIN) $(LIB_SERIAL_LINUX) $(LIB_U_CAM_TTL) -o $@


%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


install: lib_projet_vision_serial_linux.so lib_projet_vision_serial_linux.a lib_projet_vision_u_cam_ttl.so lib_projet_vision_u_cam_ttl.a 
    sudo cp -f *.h /usr/local/include/
    sudo cp -f *.so /usr/local/lib/
    sudo cp -f *.a /usr/local/lib/
    sudo cp projet_vision_dynamic /usr/bin/ 
    sudo cp projet_vision_static /usr/bin/
    sudo ldconfig

uninstall: clean
    sudo rm -f /usr/local/include/serial_linux.h
    sudo rm -f /usr/local/include/u_cam_ttl.h
    sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/lib_projet_vision_serial_linux.so
    sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/lib_projet_vision_u_cam_ttl.so
    sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/lib_projet_vision_u_cam_ttl.a
    sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/lib_projet_vison_serial_linux.a
    sudo ldconfig

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ *.so *.a
    rm -f projet_vision_static projet_vision_dynamic
```

Comment: Your question is very confuse, I didn't get it. But I don't think  `install` should be a prerequisite for `projet_vision_dynamic` and `projet_vision_static`